# Bash: Failing to Capture Exit Code of Command executed Remotely via SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian, openssh

I am using OpenSSH and have the following bash script, named **foo**, on Debian 8 (Jessie) Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@10.0.0.60 "$1"

if [[ $? ]]; then
   echo "Pass"
else
   echo "Fail"
fi
```

I am executing this script as follows:

```
root@my_host:~/bin# foo 'echo "Hello world!"'
Hello world!
Pass
root@my_host:~/bin# foo true
Pass
root@my_host:~/bin# foo false
Pass
root@my_host:~/bin# foo not_a_command
bash: not_a_command: command not found
Pass
```

I am clearly not successfully capturing the exit code of the remotely-executed command. How may I do so?

Comment: The exit code you're getting is from the `ssh` command itself.

Comment: Also, the echo-a-val method might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976289/return-value-other-that-from-ssh-session This may not work for you if you need to see live output from the session and can't afford to output extra data to the console, but there's another answer using `exit` there that might work for your situation.

Comment: Your issue is with the test. Try `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [[ $? ]]; then
```

This tests whether the value of "$?" is an empty string or not. Of course it's not, so the test always evaluates to true.

You want to do one of these:

```
if ssh root@10.0.0.60 "$1"; then
    echo pass
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Or, if you explicitly want to reference `$?`:

```
if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
    echo pass
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the fine manual for `ssh(1)`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1) we may stumble upon

```
EXIT STATUS
     ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an
     error occurred.
```

which appears to contradict your claim; with some testing one may discover

```
$ ssh root@10.0.0.60 true; echo $?
0
$ ssh root@10.0.0.60 false; echo $?
1
$
```

(unless one has a shell function that masks the real `ssh` command; try the fully qualified path to `ssh` to avoid that if that is the case) which points to the `[[ $? ]]` construct as being problematical; this is easy to test and prove

```
$ true; [[ $? ]] && echo yea
yea
$ false; [[ $? ]] && echo yea
yea
$
```

So instead one might use an equality test along the lines of

```
$ true; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo yea
yea
$ false; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo yea
$
```